# Why is my user defined definition in Xcode 13 not working?

Tags: xcode, preprocessor-directive

For debug vs. release purposes I am trying to create preprocessor definitions so that my code can be written just once as:

```
#if DEBUG_LEVEL_1
    self.status = printSimDir()
#endif
```

I have tried, and in the project section it does show the definition *see image below*

However, when debugging it's obvious that the code within the #if does not compile into the code.

Hoping that I've missed something obvious

[image]